# ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make a website with membership. All works find execpt when a member tries to change his password question and answer. I found out that the problem is exactly on this line :

`bool changeSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(model.Password, model.Question, model.Answer);`

in the call of `ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer`. I get the exception : `Specified method is not supported.` everytime I try to change the question and answer. I saw a lot of things on the web but nothing have solved my problem. Here is some important parts in my web.config

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ISAACWEBDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Does anyone has an idea what is the wrong or the missing thing I need to be able to do this?

*** EDIT : I just saw that the same thing happens with `MemberShip.GetAllUsers()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [MembershipUser.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepasswordquestionandanswer.aspx) gives a likely explanation for why this is failing:

> `PlatformNotSupportedException` - This method is not available. This
>   can occur if the application targets the .NET Framework 4 Client
>   Profile. To prevent this exception, override the method, or change the
>   application to target the full version of the .NET Framework.

It sounds like you are targeting the Client Profile for the .NET Framework 4 in your project / solution.

Comment: That was it. Briefly, I was trying to use the Framework 4 while my project was setting in Framework 4.5 . Smart me... Thanks for pointing in the right direction!